# JavaScript Object defineProperties not working

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I have learned that in Javascript we can use defineProperties to define multiple properties of object. I have therefore tried it in a simple code below but I am not quiet getting the result I wanted. It seems that the accessors is not working and I don't know why.

```
var book = {};
Object.defineProperties(book,{
 _year: {
    value: 2004 },
 edition: {
    value: 1},
 year: {
    get: function(){
    this._year;},
    set: function(value){
    if(value>2004){
     this._year = value;
     this.edition = this.edition + value - 2004;
 });
 this.year = 2016;
 alert(book.edition); //1 why??
```

Comment: You seem to be missing several `}`

Comment: Yes, I just realized I was missing those closing brackets, the formatting style did not make it clear. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple errors In your code, but the main problem is that, if you define a property with `value` then it is by default readonly:

[MDN: Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> *writable*
>       **true** if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator.
>       Defaults to **false**.

You need to add `writable: true` to make those properties writable.

So your code has to look like this (including the correction for all other errors you had):

```js
var book = {};
Object.defineProperties(book, {
  _year: {
    value: 2004,
    writable: true // << writable
  },
  edition: {
    value: 1,
    writable: true // << writable
  },
  year: {
    get: function() {
      // << missing return
      return this._year;
    },
    set: function(value) {

      if (value > 2004) {
        this._year = value;
        this.edition = this.edition + value - 2004;
      }
    }
  }
});
book.year = 2016; // << here you used this instead of book
console.log(book.edition);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Indeed I just read about that fact when using defineProperties. Enumerable, configurable, and writable are false by default.

Comment: The `return` in the getter doesn't seem to be required

Comment: @j08691 It is indeed not relevant for the given code, but it would return `undefined` if the OP tries read the property `year` at another place in the code, so I added this correction as extra info. Because otherwise this getter would not make much sense.